# Duplicate Question Confusion

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, duplicates

I recently posted [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/355379/what-is-a-word-for-deliberate-dismissal-of-some-facts) and it received very good answers. One user suggested a dupe for this question, and I agree with the designation. However, I much prefer the answers on this question than the ones from five years ago.

Which, if any, should be closed as duplicate?

Comment: @MetaEd _soooo close to voting to close as dupe_

Comment: I just voted to close as a dupe (sorry), because it really is (imo) a dupe, as you stated, too. However, *merging* is always an option.